# avoid browser image caching in webmail gmail

Tags: email, caching, gmail, html-email, webmail

Is there a way I can prevent browser image caching in an HTML email without using Javascript? I have an HTML email with an image that I want to be reloaded every time the email is opened in Gmail webmail. Right now it seems the browser is caching the image.

Comment: No, you can't stop the way Gmail processes images and no, you can't use JavaScript. Email development looks just like front-end development, but it's radically different and has a cavalcade of weird rules you need to learn to be effective. Good luck. - https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-adds-image-caching-what-you-need-to-know.

Comment: I agree with Gwally, there is no way to avoid the image caching of Gmail.

Comment: @gwally , As far as I know Gmail doing the caching is not the problem, Gmail now respects the anti-caching requests ( https://movableink.com/blog/real-time-content-and-re-open-tracking-return-to-gmail/ ). The problem is that the BROWSER itself is caching images. In regular web development you would break the caching by appending a timestamp at the end of the image SRC using Javascript, thus tricking the browser into thinking its a new/different image when the page loads. I am just trying to figure out if the same can be done for email, but without Javascript in the HTML of the email.

Comment: Gmail and just about every other email client will strip out or disable your JavaScript. You can't use JavaScript. Email development is not front-end development. Good Luck. - https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4795-using-javascript-for-emails-in-browser-view

Comment: I know I can't use Javascript, that's why I asked in my _initial_ question if there a way I can accomplish the same thing without using Javascript. If there isn't, then fine, but I thought there **might** be something with meta tags or something inline that would force the browser to not cache an image.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, since 2013 Gmail started adding images to its native web interface and mobile apps cache, but external apps and services retrieving mail from Gmail will download the normal images.

This snippet placed in the embedded CSS area can fix this issue by disabling the cache:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: thanks Perry! so do I add that snippet exactly as it's written? I thought I would have to write it as a meta tag, i.e.:

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

Comment: Umm. That looks like PHP code. I don't think you can set headers in CSS. Not that it would help anyway, since GMail uses proxies to cache images and probably ignores no-cache headers etc